# Removing borders around points in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a scatter plot with two different sets of points based on different data sets. I want one of these sets of points to have a border, therefore I have used, `pch = 21`, which changes the points into circles with a border and an interior.

I want the other set of points to have no border (for example, removing the red borders in the example below). In the example below, I have still added `pch = 21` for these points because if I don't use this, then I would have to use colour = Petal.Length, rather than fill = Petal.Length for the colour of the (interior of) the points I do not want to use `colour` instead of `fill` because I want the two sets of points to share a legend.

Is there a way to use `pch = 21` but then remove the border?

```
iris2 <- iris %>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length + 1)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = iris,
             aes(x = Sepal.Length,
                 y = Sepal.Width, 
                 fill = Petal.Length),
             pch = 21, colour = "red", size = 3) +
  geom_point(data = iris2,
           aes(x = Sepal.Length,
               y = Sepal.Width, 
               fill = Petal.Length),
           pch = 21, colour = "black", size = 3)
```

[image: Plot with red borders]

I have tried using `stroke` to change the border thickness, but while this makes the borders thicker, `stroke = 0` still gives red borders

Comment: You are adding the border with `colour = 'red'` so why not just remove that?

Comment: @Oliver Thanks - `colour = red` just changes the colour of the border - I added so it is clearer which ones I want to remove. The border is added because of `pch = 21`, which changes the points into circles with a border and an interior. If I don't use this, then I would have to use  `colour = Petal.Length`, rather than `fill = Petal.Length` for the colour of the (interior of) the points, and if I do that then the two sets of points do not have a shared legend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put `colour = Petal.Length` inside aes() and remove the colour attribute outside.

Like this:

```
ggplot() + 
     geom_point(data = iris, 
           aes(x = Sepal.Length, 
                y = Sepal.Width, 
                fill = Petal.Length, 
                colour = Petal.Length), 
           pch = 21, size = 3) + 
     geom_point(data = iris2, 
           aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, fill = Petal.Length), 
                pch = 21, colour = "black", size = 3)
```

Comment: @italianmarmite and what this example shows - ggplot is clever - it will combine both color and fill legends, even if you have different shapes... So you *can* use shape = 16

Answer (score 9):

stroke=NA removes it altogether

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = iris,
             aes(x = Sepal.Length,
                 y = Sepal.Width,
                 fill = Petal.Length),
             pch = 21, colour = "red", size = 3, stroke=NA) +
  geom_point(data = iris2,
           aes(x = Sepal.Length,
               y = Sepal.Width,
               fill = Petal.Length),
           pch = 21, colour = "black", size = 3)
```

Comment: Thanks - I can't believe I didn't try that. Tried a lot of versions of 0, blank etc.